# How to read in each line/ string in a file A, and find the line containing the string in file B and deltes it in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I know how to search for a string in a file, and delete the line with the string in it using sed.

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' ./file
```

But there are quite a few strings that I need to find, is there a way to automate this? For example read the strings line by line from file A, and pass it on as a variable to sed, so that sed could find the lines containing the string and deletes it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give example of `fileA`, `fileB` and the output you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use command substitution in combination with `sed`'s `-f`:

```
$ cat file
one two foo
bar three four
qux
quux
blah
blupp

$ cat exclude
foo
bar
^qu

$ sed -i -f <(sed 's#\(.*\)#/\1/d#g' exclude) file

$ cat file
blah
blupp
```

but this is not very robust unless you know that your patterns won't contain characters which `sed` interprets.

Better: Just use `grep` with a temp file:

```
$ grep -vf exclude file > file.new && mv file.new file

$ cat file
blah
blupp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done using `grep`.
See `man grep` for details (look for `-v` and `-f` options)

**Sample:**

```
$ cat File1
Line with pattern1
Line with jskjdksdjk
Line with ioweuwue
Line with pattern2
Line with sydsudsd

$ cat File2
pattern1
pattern2

$ grep -vf File2 File1
Line with jskjdksdjk
Line with ioweuwue
Line with sydsudsd
```

To replace the same file (`File1`), `grep -vf File2 File1 > tmp && mv tmp File1`